# Map a list of strings with JPA/Hibernate annotations

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, annotations

I want to do something like this:

```
    @Entity public class Bar {
        @Id @GeneratedValue long id;
        List<String> Foos
    }
```

and have the Foos persist in a table like this:

```
foo_bars (
    bar_id int, 
    foo varchar(64)
);
```

UPDATE:

I know how to map other entities, but it's overkill in many cases. It looks like what I'm suggesting isn't possible without creating yet another entity or ending up with everything in some blob column.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is in [Hibernate terms](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#d0e2770) a "collection of values" or "elements". There is a (Hibernate specific) annotation for it. JPA does not support this (yet).

In short, annotate your collection like this:

```
@CollectionOfElements
@JoinTable(
        table=@Table(name="..."),
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="...") // References parent
)
@Column(name="...value...", nullable=false)
```

This will create the necessary table with foreign keys and restrictions.

Comment: As of JPA 2, you can do this portably with the ElementCollection annotation, which is basically a standardised version of CollectionOfElements, and lets you have collections of Embeddables or basic types, which includes strings:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ElementCollection

Answer (score 29):

Here is how you would do this if you are using JPA2:

```
@Entity public class Bar {
   @Id @GeneratedValue long id;

   @ElementCollection
   @CollectionTable(name="foo_bars", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="bar_id"))
   @Column(name="foo")
   List<String> Foos;
 }
```

For a clearer example see section 2.2.5.3.3 in [the Hibernate Annotations Reference Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-association).

Answer (score 4):

If you store your list as an array, it works:

```
setFoos(String[] foos);
```

you can transform it like this:

```
setFoos(myList.toArray(new String[myList.size()]));
```

Answer (score 0):

create an entity 'FooBars'

refactor the attribut 'Foos' to

@OneToMany
List Foos

Comment: Thanks, Michael, but I was hoping to avoid another entity here.. I really only need the string in any case.. I was hoping to get hibernate to deal it all for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm think it's that what you need:

```
@Entity 
public class Bar {
    @Id @GeneratedValue long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="bar")   //"bar" = field name in mapping class
    List<FooBar> Foos;
}

@Entity 
public class FooBar {
    @Id @GeneratedValue long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="bar_Id")  
    Bar bar;
}
```

Comment: thanks Vanger, but I was hoping to avoid another entity here.. I really only need the string in any case.. I was hoping to get hibernate to deal it all for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here 'Foos' is List of String, So it is unidirectional.
We can do this in one model class using @ElementCollection annotation.

```
@Entity 
@Table(name="bar")
public class Bar {

        @Id @GeneratedValue 
        long id;

        @ElementCollection
        @JoinTable(
            name="foo_bars",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="bar_id")
          )
        @Column(name="foo")
        List<String> Foos;
    }
```

In DB bar_id is the foreign key in foo_bars table