# Problem in saving List<String> through JPA?

Tags: java, orm, jpa, jpa-2.0

I have already seen

[How to persist a property of type List<String> in JPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287201/how-to-persist-a-property-of-type-liststringin-jpa)

and

[Map a list of strings with JPA/Hibernate annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796347/map-a-list-of-strings-with-jpa-hibernate-annotations)

=============================================================================

I am trying to save

```
List<String>
```

through JPA. I came to know that JPA 1.0 doesn't have any way to persist collection of non-entity classes but JPA 2.0 have included `@CollectionOfElements` annotation.

First, I am not sure which JPA 2.0 implementation to use. Earlier I was using toplink-essentials but it doesn't have `@CollectionOfElements` annotation.

I downloaded eclipse-link but didn't find any jar files inside it.

So my question is to which JPA 2.0 implementation to use which provides jar files so that I can include those jars in my project as I have done for toplink-essentials.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> First, I am not sure which JPA 2.0 implementation to use. Earlier I was using toplink-essentials but it doesn't have @CollectionOfElements annotation.

TopLink-Essential is not a JPA 2.0 implementation. And as pointed out by James, note that the JPA 2.0 annotation is `@ElementCollection`, `@CollectionOfElements` is the Hibernate specific annotation which is now deprecated in favor of the JPA annotation.

> I downloaded eclipse-link but didn't find any jar files inside it.

What did you download? The *EclipseLink 2.1.1 Installer Zip (28 MB)* that you can get from the [download page](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/) contains an all-in-one jar in the jlib directory.

> So my question is to which JPA 2.0 implementation to use which provides jar files so that I can include those jars in my project as I have done for toplink-essentials.

Any of them. I would personally use Hibernate 3.5.x or EcliseLink 2.x that you can get respectively from

- https://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/hibernate3/3.5.5-Final
- http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/

#### Reference

- JPA 2.0 Specification

  - Section 11.1.12 "ElementCollection Annotation"

Answer (score 4):

Note that JPA 2.0 defines @ElementCollection not @CollectionOfElements.  It can be used to store List.  @CollectionOfElements is a Hibernate extension.

In TopLink Essentials (JPA 1.0) you could still map this, but would need to use a DescriptorCustomizer to define a DirectCollectionMapping in code.

In EclipseLink 1.0, this was defined as a @BasicCollection, and in JPA 2.0 and EclipseLink >= 1.2 this was defined as @ElemenetCollection.

Comment: Good catch, didn't pay attention to the fact that the OP was mentioning the Hibernate specific annotation.

Answer (score 1):

Just use ArrayList instead of List.
I tryed

```
@Entity
public class Orar implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private ArrayList<String> lectii;
```

and it works ;)

Comment: Your ArrayList will get serialized in a BLOB, this is totally different.